# C++ CLI XML Documentation with Forward Declaration <seealso cref> gets Reference to Unknown Symbol Warning

Tags: xml, documentation, c++-cli, forward-declaration

I have been trying to generate XML Documentation for C++ CLI, Visual Studio 2010, and I simply cannot get it to pick up a forward reference.  I made a test program to try and get it working.

I get (2 of oddly):
Warning 1   warning C4638: XML document comment applied to 'a.DoB(b)': reference to unknown symbol 'b::DoA()'.  a.h 12  1   CPPCLIGMSECExamples

The b to a one, works, with the include.  How can I make this work somehow.

Here's my sample code (cpp is just empty implementations of these, these are .h files):
a.h:

```
#pragma once

ref class b;

public ref class a
{
public:
a(void);

b^ bimpl;

/// <seealso cref="b::DoA()" />
void DoB(b^ bb);
};
```

b.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "a.h"

public ref class b
{
public:
b(void);

a^ aimpl;

/// <seealso cref="a::DoB()" />
void DoA(a^ aa);
};
```

Comment: Try putting the comment on the function body, instead of the declaration.

Comment: Ah that does work. I should've thought of that, I guess comments need to be treated as actual code. I don't really like it though, it's far nicer with everything in .h file though. What about if the <seealso cref was on the class itself? That's not in the .cpp file. Or something like a public: literal int testInt = 45; with a <seealso cref through a forward declaration. 

As a note to others, you cannot do a seealso cref to an Overloaded method from one of the other overloads, at least not with a tracking handle.  It gets weird errors and treats %s as some sort of escape char.

Comment: I understand and agree with your reasons for wanting to refer to an item before its declaration (and note, you're referring to a member, and only the class was forward declared).  My suggestion above has more value as a troubleshooting measure than as a workaround.  This limitation is unfortunate, because other documentation systems, like doxygen, don't require a declaration at all before mentioning an identifier in comments.  I would file a bug report.

Comment: For what it's worth [doxygen](http://doxygen.org) has reasonably good support for C++/CLI.  You might give it a try for your documentation extraction needs.

Comment: That's unfortunate, it's probably a big issue because Microsoft would need to restructure how these are done in the pipeline. Also it makes some of my <see crefs literally impossible unless moved to the .cpp file which makes no sense, for example.  I've heard of Doxygen and might try it, but Sandcastle does do great output.  I've had other issues too, there seems to be problems handling overloaded methods, especially ones with same signature, but one has extra parameters.  Some things just are impossible in C++ CLI, it seems.

Comment: My suggestion for the method overloading problems would again be "try doxygen, see if it fixes them".